# How to insert new data while keeping most columns value but changing some values dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using Sql Server 2005. I have this tableA with 70 columns and about 5000rows. I would like to create new data(around 200 new records) for simulation purposes. Out of the 70 columns, i only want to change values of 3 columns (TERMID, OUTLET, SNUM) the rest remains. E.g

```
    TABLEA  
    SNO  COMPANY.......TERMID........OUTLET........SNUM.....  
     1     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P5  
     1     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P4  
     2     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P4  
     1     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P3  
     3     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P3
```

so i would like to keep all values for the new records except changing all TERMID from PP2 to PP3 and all outlet from P1-P5 to P6-P8. As for SNUM all P5 will become P8, P4 will become P7 and P3 will become P6. Meaning TABLEA will look like this after i do the insert:

```
      TABLEA  
    SNO  COMPANY.......TERMID........OUTLET........SNUM.....  
     1     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P5  
     1     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P4  
     2     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P4  
     1     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P3  
     3     ABC           PP2          P1-P5         P3  
     1     ABC           PP3          P6-P8         P8  
     1     ABC           PP3          P6-P8         P7  
     2     ABC           PP3          P6-P8         P7  
     1     ABC           PP3          P6-P8         P6  
     3     ABC           PP3          P6-P8         P6
```

I do not want to do this manually as it will be very tedious for 200 rows. Is this possible using SQL statements?

I have tot of writing normal insert statements with subquery but i guess it will be as tedious or maybe even more to write INSERT INTO TABLEA ( COL1, COL2,.......COL70) VALUE (.....)

Any smart idea?

Comment: I don't understand the rules. What defines PP2 changes to PP3, and P5 = P8? Is this a one off?

Comment: So i will Insert INTO TABLEA(COL1 to 70) SELECT (COL1 to 70 then do some changes here) FROM TABLEA? THATS VERY TEDIOUS:( any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reread your response, and realize you're trying to Insert records in your current table, not create a new table.

How about:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #NewTable 
FROM TABLEA;

UPDATE #NewTable 
SET TERMID = 'PP3', 
    OUTLET= 'P6-P8', 
    SNUM = CASE 
               WHEN SNUM = 'P5' THEN 'P8'
               WHEN SNUM = 'P4' THEN 'P7'
               WHEN SNUM = 'P3' THEN 'P6'
           END;

INSERT INTO TABLEA 
SELECT * 
FROM #NewTable
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: woah seems logical...i shall try it. let me up it, for the effort

Comment: omg i got no create table permission for this DB...have to plead with my dba else really got to do it manually

Comment: :) thanks for the upvote -- without permissions, you might have to type all those out.  If you want a quick query to return all column names from the table, run something like SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'.  That way, you won't have to type them all...  Good luck.

Comment: You don't need a new table, a common table expression, aka cte, would do the job nicely.

Comment: Oh ya CTE might do that, thanks but am i able to do the update statement to a CTE?